# TSQl: Select Current Date - 6 Days and set time to 12:01 AM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to get current date -  6 days. That is easy.

Now I am trying to get current date -  6 days + 12:01 AM.

So if today is 3-2-2012 11:14 AM.

I want to get 2-25-2012 12:01 AM

These 2 selects will give me current date - 6, but will not reset the time to 12:01 AM

- select getdate()-6
- SELECT DATEADD(day, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: The solution you have chosen is the worst of the surgestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following will give you the result in a `datetime` format:

```
SELECT CAST(Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, -6, getdate()), 101) 
        + ' 12:01 AM' as datetime)
```

Result: `2012-02-25 00:01:00.000`

Once you have the datetime that you want, you can convert it to many different formats.

Or you can do the following which is in a `varchar` format:

```
select Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, -6, getdate()), 110) + ' 12:01 AM'
```

which results in `02-25-2012 12:01 AM`

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0))
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 6, '19000101'))
```

I think you will find this option faster and more flexible than the varchar implementations. by keeping the data types as they are, you don't have to worry about the vagaries of the cast/convert results.

See Louis Davidson for one of the full explainations: 
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2011/02/09/some-date-math-fun.aspx

Comment: +1 much cleaner than concatenating ugly strings. I'd probably avoid `GETDATE() - 6` though just to avoid perpetuating that date shorthand, since this methodology doesn't work with the new date/time types introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The -6 is applied to the offset, which is already an int. That actually highlights the one major downside to this technique: too many parentheses.

Comment: Yes, I understand that swapping in a DATE variable in place of GETDATE() won't break this specific code, I just think it's better practice to use explicit DATEADD for date math in general. It would probably more clear what was going on if you used a static date instead of 0; I use the 0 as well but I'm trying to break myself of that habit.

Comment: I understand now. Yes, I debated whether to add a 3rd dateadd to the code and I'm in the same boat re: 0 vs. 19000101.

Comment: @PhilHelmer - I've added my cheeky take on your answer. You can exploit the differences between the two constants and achieve a lot with a single `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair.

Answer (score 3):

One less conversion that @Phil Helmer's solution:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', GETDATE()), '1899-12-26T12:01:00')
```

Since some people are apparently unaware that everything "to the right" of the element specified in that `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair is effectively taken from the right-hand constant. Everything "to the left" (and including the actual element) can be used to achieve offsetting effects.

(The above left/right are assuming that the entire datetime value is being interpreted with year to the left and milliseconds to the right, with all intermediate values in "size" order)

---

Edited - I've also updated my answer to subsume the `-6` into the right-hand value. Its possible to create all kinds of offsetting by picking suitable values for the two constants.

---

The relationship between the two datetime constants specified in the expression ought to be expressed, at least in a comment alongside the usage. In the above, I'm using 1/1/1900 as a base point, and computing the number of midnight transitions between then and now (as `DATEDIFF` always works). I'm then adding that number of days onto the point in time 6 days earlier (e.g. 26/12/1899) at exactly 00:01 in the morning...

Comment: That's exactly why I like the DADD solution (OP:http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Date+Manipulation/69694/), it's so flexible. It could be that after a certain point of "cleverness", a calender table has some advantages, but if the offsets, rules, etc. are prone to change, the DADD comes to the fore again. BTW, it should also be noted that the use of the date literal formats he uses here are always interpreted the same, regardless of collation/localization (see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/d0f28d86-fea1-40f6-b982-65f6849b9eca)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -6, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) + '12:01'
```

Comment: You missed the part where he wants 6 days ago.